# MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` is a string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, web-deployment

When I try to deploy my app on heroku  it gives me this error:

> MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.

when I deploy the app locally, it works fine.
**I read other question and the common solution is to move the .env file into the root directory.
*The problem is I have it already there.***
I think I'm doing something wrong on passing the db dsn to the mongoose.connect() function.

> here the imports in app.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session) //session come argomento
const compression = require('compression') //session come argomento

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

require('dotenv').config();
const config = require('./config/Config.js'); // [process.env.NODE_ENV || 'test']
const datiRegioniAPI = require('./DatiRegioniAPI');
const db = require ('./lib/db.js');
const userService = require('./services/UserService.js');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const aut = require('./lib/aut.js');
const helmet = require("helmet")
const app = express();
```

> here the db.connect function in app.js file:

```
db.connect(config.production.dsn)
   .then(()=>{
      app.listen(port,(err)=>{
         if(err){console.error(err, "### ERRORE CONNESSIONE DB");}
         else{console.log("connected on ", port);}
      })
   })
   .catch((err)=>{
      console.error(err, "### CATCH error db connection");
   })
```

> this is my config.js file:

```
const path = require("path");


module.exports = {
    data:{
        avatars: path.join(__dirname, "../data/avatars")
    },
    test : {
        dsn: process.env.TEST_DB_DSN,
    },
    production : {
        dsn: process.env.PRODUCTION_DB_DSN,
    }
}
```

> this is my db.js file:
>
> > I basically export this function to app.js file as middleware

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);



module.exports.connect = async dsn => {
    mongoose.connect(dsn) 
}
```

> It's a weird issue cause it works fine locally but does not work at
> all when deploying on heroku

Answer (score 0):

When deploying an app to production

> require('dotenv').config()

is not effective and you won't find the variables in production environment. therefore my solution was to manually add the env varibles in Heroku and in case of NODE_ENV=='production' use those variables.